How to determine the maximum static TLS (Thread Local Storage) Block Size on Linux?
Problem
Trying to run this code
if (!dlopen("../lib/libMy.so", RTLD_NOW)) {
    std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

resulted in this TLS (Thread Local Storage) error:

cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

Solution
Dumping the Thread Local Storage section .tbss (static and non static non-initialized thread local variables) shows Tls_ErrorStruct size is 600 bytes (0x258) and Tls_tv is 1600 bytes (0x640), totaling 2200 TLS bytes:
$ objdump -C -t ../lib/libMy.so | grep -F '.tbss'

00000000000008e8 l       .tbss  0000000000000008              runtime.tlsg
0000000000000010 l       .tbss  0000000000000001              __tls_guard
0000000000000688 l       .tbss  0000000000000001              __tls_guard
...
0000000000000690 g       .tbss  0000000000000258              Tls_ErrorStruct
...
0000000000000018 g       .tbss  0000000000000640              Tls_tv

To fix the block error, those thread_local variables were reduced to ~600 bytes. The dlopen now succeeds.
Note
To check how much Thread Local Storage (TLS) is needed 0x0008f0
$ readelf -Wl ../lib/libMy.so

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 10 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset    VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000  0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x48ada8 0x48ada8 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x48b000  0x000000000048b000 0x000000000048b000 0xdab271 0xdab271 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x1237000 0x0000000001237000 0x0000000001237000 0x2c0564 0x2c0564 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x14f76a0 0x00000000014f86a0 0x00000000014f86a0 0xd16172 0xd6ec50 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x20b58c0 0x00000000020b68c0 0x00000000020b68c0 0x000220 0x000220 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000270  0x0000000000000270 0x0000000000000270 0x000088 0x000088 R   0x4
  TLS            0x14f76a0 0x00000000014f86a0 0x00000000014f86a0 0x000001 0x0008f0 R   0x8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x13fa440 0x00000000013fa440 0x00000000013fa440 0x02358c 0x02358c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000  0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x14f76a0 0x00000000014f86a0 0x00000000014f86a0 0xbc3960 0xbc3960 R   0x1

Source
Question
I'm not sure how to find the dynamic loader Thread Local Storage block size but did find a possible reference here:
/* Size of the static TLS block.  Giving this initialized value
   preallocates some surplus bytes in the static TLS area.  */
size_t _dl_tls_static_size = 2048;

Is there a linux tool or some C++ method to determine the max Thread Local Storage block size?

TLS means Transport Layer Security to most people. Don't overuse TLAs.

The reason libTestTLS.so loads successfully in this answer is that the tread-local variable is never used.
gdb -q ./LoadTLS

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40117f: file LoadTLS.c, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/tls/LoadTLS
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at LoadTLS.c:5
5           void* handle = dlopen("./libTestTLS.so", RTLD_NOW);
(gdb) n
6           if (!handle) {
(gdb) p handle
$1 = (void *) 0x4172d0
(gdb) p tv
The inferior has not yet allocated storage for thread-local variables in
the shared library `./libTestTLS.so'
for Thread 0x7ffff7a7d240 (LWP 176)

If you add an actual use for it:
class ThreadVector
{
public:
    char tlsBlock[1 * 1024 * 1024];
};

thread_local ThreadVector tv;

#if defined(FN)
char* fn()
{
  return tv.tlsBlock;
}
#endif

and rebuild the library with g++ -g -fPIC -shared -o libTestTLS.so TestTLS.c -ftls-model=initial-exec -DFN, then you can see the failure:
./LoadTLS
Failed to load library: ./libTestTLS.so: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block


Followed your example and also got the error: Failed to load library: ./libTestTLS.so: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block. Thanks!

This is not technically an answer since I don't want to experiment with this, just a line of thought on a possible fix. Yes, I'm lazy like that, when it comes to stuff that doesn't affect me.
For starters, while we have a limited number of "thread local keys" in the pthread tls API, that API isn't used so it doesn't matter. Instead, Linux uses ELF sections for its thread local storage, which imposes no limits.
The limit you are running into comes from dlopen() opening a module that the initial loader hasn't seen. Now, the _dl_tls_static_size symbol that you found appears to exist to handle this case to some extent, by just making the loader allocate a bit more memory. However, following up on that symbol, you'll find this comment:
  /* That is the size of the TLS memory for this object.  The initialized
     value of _dl_tls_static_size is provided by dl-open.c to request some
     surplus that permits dynamic loading of modules with IE-model TLS.  */

The word that sticks out here is "IE-model", suggesting that other "models" might exist that don't need this. If you look at gcc options, you'll find this:
-ftls-model=model

    Alter the thread-local storage model to be used (see Thread-Local Storage). The model argument should be one of ‘global-dynamic’, ‘local-dynamic’, ‘initial-exec’ or ‘local-exec’. Note that the choice is subject to optimization: the compiler may use a more efficient model for symbols not visible outside of the translation unit, or if -fpic is not given on the command line.

    The default without -fpic is ‘initial-exec’; with -fpic the default is ‘global-dynamic’.

And yeah, we have a model initial-exec, which could easily be abbreviated as IE, which is what we saw in the comment.
Thus, if you have control over how this shared object is compiled, it might be worth trying global-dynamic instead.

No luck applying the option -ftls-model=global-dynamic to the shared object. The only fix that worked was to reduce or remove LARGE thread local objects such as char err_info[512];. Thanks!

@vengy That's annoying :-(

I was unable to reproduce the error

cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

The following creates a 1MB static thread local tv but loads correctly using dlopen, so I can't explain why the initial problem exists when using 2200 bytes?
g++ -fPIC -shared TestTLS.cpp -o libTestTLS.so
// TestTLS.cpp
#include <iostream>

class ThreadVector
{
public:
    char tlsBlock[1 * 1024 * 1024];
};

thread_local ThreadVector tv;

g++ LoadTLS.cpp -o LoadTLS -ldl
// LoadTLS.cpp
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    void* handle = dlopen("./libTestTLS.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load library: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}

objdump -C -t libTestTLS.so | grep -F '.tbss'
0000000000000000 g       .tbss  0000000000100000              tv

readelf -Wl libTestTLS.so
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 12 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000800 0x000800 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x00026d 0x00026d R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x00012c 0x00012c R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002de0 0x0000000000003de0 0x0000000000003de0 0x000268 0x000270 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x002df8 0x0000000000003df8 0x0000000000003df8 0x0001d0 0x0001d0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x0002e0 0x00000000000002e0 0x00000000000002e0 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  NOTE           0x000300 0x0000000000000300 0x0000000000000300 0x000024 0x000024 R   0x4
  TLS            0x002de0 0x0000000000003de0 0x0000000000003de0 0x000000 0x100000 R   0x1
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0002e0 0x00000000000002e0 0x00000000000002e0 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00201c 0x000000000000201c 0x000000000000201c 0x00003c 0x00003c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x002de0 0x0000000000003de0 0x0000000000003de0 0x000220 0x000220 R   0x1

Update
Based upon the comment, I added this option -ftls-model=initial-exec
but the shared library still loaded without any errors? I was expecting to see the error

cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

For example, here are the build commands g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
test@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TLS$ g++ -fPIC -shared -ftls-model=initial-exec TestTLS.cpp -o libTestTLS.so
test@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TLS$ g++ LoadTLS.cpp -o LoadTLS -ldl
test@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TLS$ ./LoadTLS
test@ubuntu:~/Desktop/TLS$ 

Note
Can anyone else get the error to appear?
Seems like a bug somewhere or the dynamic linker/loader still finds a way to allocate the necessary TLS space without defaulting to the restrictions implied by initial-exec.

The reason you can't reproduce is that shared libraries default to global-dynamic TLS model, which imposes no limit on TLS size. Somehow your real library is linked with initial-exec TLS model. Use readelf -Wr and look for R_X86_64_TPOFF64 relocations (these refer to the "Offset in initial TLS block" -- see comment in /usr/include/elf.h).

I've added an answer explaining why you didn't reproduce the error and how  to change your test so the error is reproduced.
